# How to patch base class method?

Tags: python, python-mock

I have two classes:

```
class A(object):
    def get_something(self):
        return 1

class B(A):
    pass
```

and when I try to patch A.get_something in tests it fails.

```
from some_module.myclasses import B

...
def test_something(self):
    with patch('some_module.myclasses.A.get_something', return_value=2):
        self.assertEqual(B().get_something(), 2)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Found out. I have to patch imported `A`

```
from some_module.myclasses import A, B

...
def test_something(self):
    with patch.object(A, 'get_something', return_value=2):
        self.assertEqual(B().get_something(), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct but if it isn't working, it may be because of other modules importing `A` or `B` into their namespace and not using the same package as what you patched.

I have seen this happen when you do something like this:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    mod.py
```

Python modules

`mypackage/mod.py`

```
class A(object):
    def get_something(self):
        return 1
```

`mypackage/__init__.py`

```
from mod import *
```

Then `mypackage.mod.A` may be imported as `mypackage.A` but your patching `mypackage.mod.A`

Comment: Nope, I'm not importing it in `__init__.py`. But thanks for suggestion